# Powershell - Export Multiple CSV's into unique folders

Tags: powershell, csv

I have been working on a PowerShell script for the better part of well a week or two. I've been able to get some parts of it working however I'm unable to fully get this automated.

I deal with a lot of CSV files on a daily basis, I have been tasked with uploading them into our software however sometimes they're too large to handle so I break them down based upon their "type" (it's a column in the CSV) and I export it to a single CSV per "type". I've been able to accomplish this with the following:

```
$file = gci -Filter "*.csv";
Import-Csv $file `
| Group-Object –Property “type” `
| Foreach-Object `
    { 
        $path=$_.name+”.csv” ; $_.group `
        | Export-Csv –Path $path –NoTypeInformation 
    }
```

So this works wonderfully, for each individual CSV. Unfortunately I don't have the time to do this for each individual CSV. Now I come to my other PowerShell script:

```
get-childitem -Filter "*.csv" `
| select-object basename `
    | foreach-object{ $path=$_.basename+".csv" #iterate through files.
        if(!(Test-Path -path $_.basename)) #If the folder of the file can't be found then it will attempt to create it.
        {
            New-Item $_.basename -type directory; $file=$_.basename+".csv";
            Import-Csv $file `
            | Group-Object -Property "Type" `
            | Foreach-Object {
                $path=$_.name+".csv"; $_.group `
                |  ` 
                    if(!(Test-Path -path $path2))
                    {
                        New-Item $path2 -type directory
                        Export-Csv -Path $path2 + "\" + $path -NoTypeInformation
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        "Failed on: " + $_.basename
                        #Export-Csv -Path $_.basename + "\" + $path -NoTypeInformation
                    }                    
                }
        }
        else
        {
        Import-Csv $path `
            | Group-Object -Property "Type" `
            | Foreach-Object {$path=$_.basename+".csv" ; $_.group                     
                if(Test-Path -path $._)
                    {
                        New-Item $path2 -type directory
                        Export-Csv -Path $path2 + "\" + $path -NoTypeInformation
                    }
                    #else
                    #{
                        Write-Host "Failed on: $_.basename"
                        #Export-Csv -Path $_.basename + "\" + $path -NoTypeInformation
                    #}                    
                }                
        }
}
```

I just can't wrap my head around "why" this isn't working effectively. I have two conditionals. Is there a folder for the CSV? If no create one. I have to have another one because one of the "types" contains a \ which errors out if I don't have the folder, so I automatically try to create it. When I run the script I get the Path is null.

The Error is:

> The term ' ' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
>   script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
>   if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>       At C:\Users\c.burkinshaw\foldermake.ps1:11 char:26
>       +                     |  `  <<<< 
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ( :String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>
> ```
> Test-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
> At C:\Users\c.burkinshaw\foldermake.ps1:12 char:45
> +                         if(!(Test-Path -path <<<<  $path2))
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Test-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand
> ```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, if you have questions please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Where do you get the path is null error?

Comment: According to the error: Line 11 Char 26 or Line 12 Char 45

`$path=$_.name+".csv"; $_.group `
                |  `

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined `$path2` anywhere, so something like `test-path -path $path2` will say path is null. And in one place you are using `$._` which will again give errors.

Edit after question updated with error message:

Your error message also says the same

> Test-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is
>   null. At C:\Users\c.burkinshaw\foldermake.ps1:12 char:45
>   +                         if(!(Test-Path -path <<<<  $path2))

Also the other error is in:

```
$path=$_.name+".csv"; $_.group `
                |  `
```

what are you trying to do here with the `$_.group`?

It is not proper. You cannot do `$_.group |` and provide some if statement.

Other comments:

Why are using `$_.basename` and then appending `.csv`? You could have  just used `$_.name`. Try to not use the `select-object basename` - I don't see the value.

Extract the common import-csv and export-csv part into a function.

Comment: I had tried something new and forgot to remove the `$path2` variable. The $._ portion was another piece I was debugging, I was simply deleting the folders after they were created so I could try to get one part working correctly. I chose `$_.basename` due to creating folders with the name of the CSV. I'm very new to PowerShell so I didn't even think to try functions...

Comment: @Anubis - From the error it clearly shows that the error is in `if(!(Test-Path -path <<<<  $path2))` and because `$path2` is not defined!

Comment: The `$_.group` is for grouping the CSV items into their respective sets. I'm organizing them by type which is the column name, then this allows me to create an individual CSV for each type.